# Jetpack compose navigation bar

Tags: android, jetpack

why bottom navigation bar material 3 has no option to set duration for indicator expation animation

here is the navigation item is screenshot from the source code of it:
[image]

here is the inner of that function which is for animation set:
[image]

as u can see that harcoded no option by user pefered

the problem is that default duration is too fast if i see material 3 guidelines that not as fast like this jetpack compose

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's a good point. I'm currently exploring ways to implement a “customizable layer” on top of Compose Material Design components, where specific parts could be overridden and customized for a more tailored look.

I'm still in the early stages of exploration, but I've already built a custom Navigation Bar as a proof of concept. You can check it out here on GitHub and let me know your thoughts on the idea: https://github.com/yveskalume/open-material

Comment: thanks, could you please give me official material design component repository for compose

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/compose/material3/material3